# Azure - Storage queue message renewal

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-storage-queues

We are using azure web job for processing the messages in azure storage queue. After the 5 unsuccessful attempts messages are moved to the Poisson queue. Instead of that i want to process the message further more until the message have been processed successfully.

kindly assist me on the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can [configure](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Queues#config) the maximum number of retries (default is 5) before a message is sent to the poison queue. You can add an 'int dequeCount' parameter to your method to check the number of times it has been called and base your decisions on that.

Having said that you should definitely have some error handling strategy in place. Just trying indefinitely till you succeed is a recipe for failure.

Comment: static void Main()
        {
            var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

            config.Queues.VisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
            config.Queues.MaxDequeueCount=100;
            if (config.IsDevelopment)
            {
                config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
            }
            var host = new JobHost(config);
            host.RunAndBlock();
        }.used MaxDequeueCount property. But still the messages are moved to possion. Instead of that i want to process the message continuously for 5 days without moving to poisson.